# Glassfish Bean Reference Lookup Fails

Tags: java, glassfish-3

Wierd problem here. I have a bean with a remote interface declared and an implementation defined as a Stateless bean. Since I want to be able to replace the bean with a different bean depending on the implementation requirements, I have an `ejb-reference` declared in `glassfish-web.xml`.

I can successfully inject the bean if I use the name syntax to refer to the reference name like    `@EJB(name = "BeanReference")`. I can also do a lookup: `new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/BeanReference")`.

The weird thing happens when I don't have any injections at all (no `@EJB`). Then the lookup fails with "`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/BeanReference`". If I list the pairs in "`java:comp/env`" it confirms that the reference doesn't exist unless an `@EJB` injection occurs somewhere in the application. I have checked the jndi-name entry and confirmed it matches the output from Glassfish during initialization.

I also tried using `@Local` instead of `@Remote` and get the same results. I prefer the `@Remote` since in an actual deployment the `MyBean` implementation will likely reside on a remote glassfish instance. It is local only for development and testing.

Using Glassfish 3.1.1 and NetBeans 7.1.2. Code snippets below...exception handling omitted for clarity.

```
@Remote
public interface MyBean {
    public String doSomething();
}

@Stateless
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean {
    @Override
    public String doSomething() {
        return "something";
    }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyOtherBean {
    public MyOtherBean() {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        MyBean myBean = (MyBean)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/BeanReference");
        String rc = myBean.doSomething();
        System.out.println("rc = " + rc);
    }
}

<ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>BeanReference</ejb-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:global/appName/MyBeanImpl!com.test.bean.MyBean</jndi-name>
</ejb-ref>
```

Comment: For the time being I added a dummy bean that injects the reference and it works. The bean is stateless and never referenced.